# How to make three spinner that content (district,subdistrict head, urban village head)

Tags: android, json, spinner

How to make three spinner that content *(district, subdistrict head, urban village head...)* using webservice JSON?

How to link query and webservice JSON in three spinner?

Problems with three Spinner webservice JSON query.

[image: Problems with three Spinner webservice JSON query]

Comment: first get district json from webservice and store in first spinner. when spinner item clicked, call subdistrct api with selected value

Answer (score 0):

Add three spinners in your xml code. Convert that json response1 into listview & add it to spinner1. Make service call for response2 when spinner1 is selected.

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findviewbyid(R.id.spinner1);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
R.layout.spinner_layout, service_response_1);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This may help you.